# App that lets me set the default font for a font-family

Tags: linux, ubuntu, font-utility

I am looking for a program for Ubuntu/Linux that allows me to set the default font for each font-family.

As example: I want to use the font "Roboto" as the default font for the "sans-serif" family.

I want to use a GUI rather then a command line tool, but I'll accept a command line solution, if it is easy and neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer

A tool specifically developed for such task is `pyfontfixer` (This is the tool I actually used and forgot it's name and question is just to find it. Now I found it). It is pretty straightforward. Here is a screenshot of this tool.

[image: pyfontfixer image]

### Old Answer

One such tool available for Linux is Font-Manager. It can be installed on Ubuntu using command

```
sudo apt-get install font-manager
```

or from Software Center. Open up this software and click on the **Set Font Preference** button on bottom of it and Select **Alias Editor**

[image]

Then on the new window, click on the **Add Alias** button and type the generic name of the family, such as `sans-serif`, then click **Add Substitute** button and type or select the font name you want to replace with.

[image]

It should now replace the generic family `sans-serif` with the selected font.